# Android: Closing the application and opening it from recent list

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked so many times on SO, so take a moment before you down vote it. I have gone through [How to remove application from recent application list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list)

[Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon?rq=1)

[Close application and remove from recent apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps)

And many other questions on SO.

In my application I'm storing the user login details in SharedPreferences. Basically when my application starts - Activity A - Splash screen will show up from 3 seconds. Then it will go to Activity B - The user login page, on press of login the credentials are stored in SharedPreference. Then it will go to Activity C - Home page. 
I don't want the user to enter the login details each time so I'm storing them in SharedPreference, if the value is present then redirect directly to Activity C - Home Page.

So the flow is like this,

**If SharedPreference is empty**

```
A->B->C
```

**If values are present in SharedPreference**

```
A->B->C, I'm checking in Activity B and when the values are present redirect it to C without making the B to come to front.
```

This all works fine if I open application from launcher. But if I open it from  recent list even though the values are present in SharedPreference it is going to Activity B. And when I open it from launcher or recent list the Activity A (splash screen) doesn't show up. Only if I logout and open the application it shows up. What would be the problem?

I tired putting `<activity android:excludeFromRecents="true">` so forcing it to not to appear in recent list. Even after this if I open it from launcher it goes to login page i.e Activity B.

I'm overriding the back button like this on Activity C

```
public void onBackPressed() {


    if (backPressedOnce) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.backPressedOnce = true;

    Toast.makeText(this, "Please press back again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            backPressedOnce = false; 

        }
    }, 3000);



} 

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    this.backPressedOnce = false ;
}
```

So I have two questions

Q1) How to make splash screen appear each time the user launches it?
Q2) If launched from recent list, why it is not redirecting to Activity C even when SharedPreference has values?

Sorry to ask very lengthy question, I know it is not appropriate. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i will put my thoughts...

1. why r u checking sharedpreference in B at all? if u have stored in sharedprefernce redirect the user directly to C from A .

   if(sharedPreference) -> C

   else B -> C
2. when u are launching from recent afaik it will call onresume and not oncreate and also i believe you are checking in oncreate hence its not executing when launching from recent , use logs to know the cycle also please refer to activity life cycle.
3. if u dont need the activity to exist u can call finish() and also put noHistory='true' in manifest...

plz see to these points and rectify me if i m wrong anywhere...

thx and hope it helps u...

Comment: I can see activity A only when I run it for the first time and I logout. If values are present in SharedPreferences it is not launching.

Comment: See #2 of this answer. You can close C and start A from there. It can be a problem though if screen orientation changed - you have no way of knowing if OnResume was called by that or by launch from recents. Oh, and BTW: "launch" from recents is actually only bringing the app back to front, it was never killed in the first place. You can use #3 in OnPause if you want to kill it.