# Remove application from Recent app while closing the activity

Tags: android

I have the requirement to close the activity as soon as it get launched,to achieve  this i used finish() method, but it still exists in running application list.

Please suggest me some solution..

Comment: what you're saying doesn't make sense. After you finish an activity, it shouldn't exist in memory unless you are leaking it

Comment: The activity you're calling the finish() method from is destroyed and all its resources are queued for garbage collection, because a reference to this activity becomes inaccessible. So, all memory that was used by this activity will be freed during next GC cycle.

Comment: and the app won't be finished only the activity is get closed. Android keeps processes around in case the user wants to restart the app, this makes the startup phase faster. The process will not be doing anything and if memory needs to be reclaimed, the process will be killed. Don't worry about it :)

Comment: After launching an activity, the activity is getting closed, but still its there in list of running application? I want to remove it from Running application list..

Comment: Do you mean by **Recent apps** ? then please have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385366/2591002)

Comment: Thanks for Reply..This is my requirement, is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 4):

The activity you're calling the `finish()` method, is destroyed and all its resources are queued for garbage collection, because a reference to this activity becomes inaccessible. So, all memory that was used by this activity will be freed during next GC cycle. and by findihing teh activity, you are destroying the actviity not the app..

### Please keep in mind :

> Android keeps processes around in case the user wants to restart the app, this makes the startup phase faster. The process will not be doing anything and if memory needs to be reclaimed, the process will be killed. Don't worry about it :)

To remove your app from `Recent app` list : *just specify `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in the manifest*

[Refer this link 
for better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753359/2591002)