# I am not able to finish/close my application

Tags: android, android-activity

I have used Open Finish Activity using intent here :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(yourScreen.this,Finish.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```

Then I have used.

```
public class Finish extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);  //  1)Option
    System.exit(0);                    //  2)Option
    finish();                          //  3)Option
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); //4)last
 }}
```

I have try all options

here my Application gone in background. 
when i click my hardware apps menu button then its appear in list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try it for us, please? :D

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     finishAndRemoveTask();
} else {
     finish();
}
```

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        } else {
            finish();
        }

Comment: Awesome! Could you upvote and mark it as the correct answer, please? Cheers :D