# Using finishAndRemoveTask() method of Activity class on API levels lower than 21

Tags: android, activity-finish, systemexit

I need to delete app from recently used apps list. There is no problem on API level 21 and above. I use finishAndRemoveTask() method. But that method cannot be used on API levels lover than 21. How can I call that method on API levels lover than 21?

I tried that solutions but they does not work :

[Close application and remove from recent apps/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with that library :

https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash

Answer (score 3):

Prease, check code below

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    else
        finish();
    System.exit(0);
```