# When taskAffinity activity is calling finish() but it is not dismiss recent apps

Tags: android, android-activity, taskaffinity

I have taskAffinity activity which is `BActivity` and `AActivity` is a normal activity.

`AActivity` is calling `BActivity` by using below `startActivity` function. When `BActivity's` jobs have done, `BActivity` called `finish();` function but `BActivity` doesn't dismiss recent applications.

startActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where am I doing wrong?

**AndroidManifest:**

```
          <activity
            android:name=".BActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=".AActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>

          <activity
             android:name=".AActivity"
             android:configChanges="locale"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close application and remove from recent apps/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps)

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use for upper SDK 21

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

and lower 21 use

```
finish();
```