# Android - How to close app after opening a website

Tags: android

I developed a very simple app which just opens our companies website.

I had to program it in a way, so that it asks the user in which browser he wants to open the website, because WebView is missing some features and has some bugs.

**Full code:**

```
package XXX;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public void openWebPage(String url)
    {
        Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openWebPage("https://www.example.com");
        finish();   // I also tried: System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The user is getting asked which browser he likes the website to be opened with. After that, the browser opens and loads the website.

**Problem**: The app is still open, even though I need it to get closed at this point.

[image]

How can I close the app after it startet the browser?

I tried `finish()` and even `System.exit(0)`, both failed.

Comment: where are you calling finish?

Comment: In `onCreate` as seen in the code.

Comment: did you tried `finishAffinity()` ?

Comment: @VivekMishra, I just tried it, same result.

Comment: Also when you want to close your app, why are you calling `startActivityForResult()` ?

Comment: Perhaps you should try calling `finish()` in onPause/onStop method of the activity before super.onPause/Stop. Have you tried that by any chance?

Comment: `The app is still open` why do you think so?

Comment: @VivekMishra, im not sure. It was at `startActivity(intent)` previously.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, see the screenshot

Comment: @Black that shows **recent** apps, not **open** apps

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, no, it shows the open apps

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, because I know my phone

Comment: It does show the recent apps instead of open apps

Comment: Looks like you don't know it. Android shows the **recent** apps, not open

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, then how can I remove it from there?

Comment: you basically can't. You can only set your app to not to show in recent apps at all

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, ok thank you. I will research.

Comment: You can remove it from recent

Comment: Add a flag for your activity in manifest exclude recent

Comment: @VivekMishra, this won't *remove* it from recents, but will **prevent it from appearing there**

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if it will not appear, then there is no need to worry about removing

Comment: @VivekMishra not if he wants it to disappear after the browser is open.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but the flag will be added to the activity which will open the browser so it will done before the browser is opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Activity is finished,it is just showing in recent apps. Doesn't mean it is open. What you need to do it to exclude your activity from recent apps. It is as simple as adding a tag in Manifest file. If you set `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` like shown below, it will stop the activity from showing up in recent apps list, which is what you are looking for:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this flag when starting your activity:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS

This means it will be excluded from the the recents (i.e. when you call `finish()` it won't appear anywhere else as recently opened).

Other questions:

[Remove app from recent apps programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically)

[Close application and remove from recent apps/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: any reason for answering instead of marking as duplicate?

Comment: because the question is worded differently, they may want to clarify etc etc. Always find it a bit ruthless when ppl's questions just get closed straightaway.

Comment: I aggree, you're right.